# Hiding gridlines in rCharts - nPlot

Tags: r, rcharts

I'm currently trying to create a scatter chart using the R package rCharts without the x and y axis gridlines. Unfortunately i do not have very much experience with javascript. I have attempted using the after script setTemplate argument.

```
library(rCharts)

a <- rep(1:10,10)
b <- rep(unique(morse_code$month_x),9)
b <- b[-(1:8)]
c <- rep(1:10,10)

abc <- data.frame(a,b,c)

a1 <- nPlot(a ~ b, data = abc, type = 'scatterChart')
a1$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Year Month')
a1$yAxis(axisLabel = 'Volume')

a1$setTemplate(
  afterScript = "   <script>
ySlope.gridlineShapes.remove();
   <script>")

a1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
a1$setTemplate(
  afterScript = "<style>
.tick line {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>")
```

Comment: Brilliant worked perfectly victor. The issues were both the <script> , and the method used to remove the lines. Do you have a recommended guide/tutorial to become more proficient with this.